# PostgreSQL public access to database

Tags: postgresql, public

I recently created a test database but I would like it to be accessible to all users.

I created the database as user postgres then use the command

```
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE dbname TO public;
```

But when I log out and try to connect to it with a different user I get this error

```
psql -d dbname
psql: FATAL:  role "username" does not exist
```

I don't want to have to create a user for each person who will be accessing the database which is the reason i wanted to make it public. Is there a permission that I am still missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although access to everybody (`public`) is granted, the user you connect with has to exist. The default for `psql` is the username of your system account. You can, of course, create a passwordless `anonymous` user everybody can use to connect:

```
psql -U anonymous dbname
```

Comment: Or the equivalent `psql dbname anonymous`, +1

Comment: doesn't that defeat the point of granting public access to the database, it's not really public if you have to be a user to connect to it

Comment: Public in this context means "every user the DBMS knows about"